# Citrix SSO hidden proxy setting

Tags: big-sur, vpn, apple-silicon

I have a strange VPN software from my company (Citrix SSO)
Recently my company deployed a wrong proxy config
The odd behaviour is that this client is able to configure a forced proxy on my mac
even if all the network interfaces on my mac has no proxy, all the apps (commandline, browsers, all other apps) are going through a proxy (127.0.0.1:8888)

Do you know where this configuration is stored ?

MacOS 11.5.1 (M1)

This is unrelated to [Where is the "Send all traffic over VPN connection" setting in OSX 10.9 Mavericks?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144572/where-is-the-send-all-traffic-over-vpn-connection-setting-in-osx-10-9-maverick)

the routing table on the mac is not modified only a forced proxy is configured and its configuration is not visibile in system settings.

Comment: If it is wrong, why not reach out to your company and have them fix the config?

Comment: Sys pref > Network > WiFi (probably) > advanced > Proxies. Also, Firefox allows for custom proxy config.

Comment: @nohillside they have no clue

Comment: @anki I said "even if all the network interfaces on my mac has no proxy"